# Objects with data into object with list of keys and values - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures

I'm struggling with serializing data into a new structure and hope to find a better solution for it.

I have data that comes from API in this structure:

```
  const filters = {
     category: ['Football', 'Soccer'],
     subcategory: ['Tactic', 'Frighting'],
     action: ['Kicking', 'Shooting']
  };
```

And I want to convert it into this structure:

```
const options = {
category: [
    {
        value: 'Football',
        label: 'Football'
    },
    {
        value: 'Soccer',
        label: 'Soccer'
    }
],
subCategory: [
    {
        value: 'Tactic',
        label: 'Tactic'
    },
    {
        value: 'Frighting',
        label: 'Frighting'
    }
],
action: [
    {
        value: 'Kicking',
        label: 'Kicking'
    },
    {
        value: 'Shooting',
        label: 'Shooting'
    }
]
};
```

Help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: So you want `subcategory` to be `subCategory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reduce and map you can loop over the object and transform it.

```js
  const filters = {
     category: ['Football', 'Soccer'],
     subcategory: ['Tactic', 'Frighting'],
     action: ['Kicking', 'Shooting']
  };

const keyConversion = {
  subcategory: 'subCategory'
}

const result = Object.entries(filters).reduce((obj, [key, arr]) => {
  const mappedKey = keyConversion[key] || key;
  obj[mappedKey] = arr.map(val => ({ name: val, value: val }));
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, what if I have new structure like that: "sports":{ category: [
    {
        value: 'Football',
        label: 'Football'
    },
    {
        value: 'Soccer',
        label: 'Soccer'
    }
],
subcategory: [
    {
        value: 'Tactic',
        label: 'Tactic'
    },
    {
        value: 'Frighting',
        label: 'Frighting'
    }
],
action: [
    {
        value: 'Kicking',
        label: 'Kicking'
    },
    {
        value: 'Shooting',
        label: 'Shooting'
    }]
}}; ----- without changing the subcategory to subCategory and with one top layer above

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like :

```
let options = Object.keys(filters).map(key => {
  return {
    [key]: filters[key].map(filter => {
      return {
        value: filter,
        label: filter
      }
    })

  }
})
```

```js
const filters = {
  category: ['Football', 'Soccer'],
  subcategory: ['Tactic', 'Frighting'],
  action: ['Kicking', 'Shooting']
}

let options = Object.keys(filters).map(key => {
  return {
    [key]: filters[key].map(filter => {
      return {
        value: filter,
        label: filter
      }
    })

  }
})

console.log(options)
```

Comment: Hi, what if I have new structure like that: "sports":{ category: [ { value: 'Football', label: 'Football' }, { value: 'Soccer', label: 'Soccer' } ], subcategory: [ { value: 'Tactic', label: 'Tactic' }, { value: 'Frighting', label: 'Frighting' } ], action: [ { value: 'Kicking', label: 'Kicking' }, { value: 'Shooting', label: 'Shooting' }] }}; ----- without changing the subcategory to subCategory and with one top layer above –

Comment: please update your question with indented json with more details

Answer (score 0):

Use `for..in` to iterate over `Object` and `.map` array helper

```js
const filters = {
  category: ['Football', 'Soccer'],
  subcategory: ['Tactic', 'Frighting'],
  action: ['Kicking', 'Shooting']
};

const result = {}
for (key in filters) {
  result[key] = filters[key].map(v => ({value: v, label: v}))
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi, what if I have new structure like that: "sports":{ category: [ { value: 'Football', label: 'Football' }, { value: 'Soccer', label: 'Soccer' } ], subcategory: [ { value: 'Tactic', label: 'Tactic' }, { value: 'Frighting', label: 'Frighting' } ], action: [ { value: 'Kicking', label: 'Kicking' }, { value: 'Shooting', label: 'Shooting' }] }}; ----- without changing the subcategory to subCategory and with one top layer above –

Answer (score 0):

You can map the entires of the object to a new `[key, value]` entries, where the value is a mapped version of your arrays. Once you have the new `[key, value]` pair arrays you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build your resulting object:

```js
const filters = {category: ['Football', 'Soccer'], subcategory: ['Tactic', 'Frighting'], action: ['Kicking', 'Shooting'] };
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(filters).map(
  ([k, arr]) => [k, arr.map(v => ({value:v, label:v}))]
));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi, what if I have new structure like that: "sports":{ category: [ { value: 'Football', label: 'Football' }, { value: 'Soccer', label: 'Soccer' } ], subcategory: [ { value: 'Tactic', label: 'Tactic' }, { value: 'Frighting', label: 'Frighting' } ], action: [ { value: 'Kicking', label: 'Kicking' }, { value: 'Shooting', label: 'Shooting' }] }}; ----- without changing the subcategory to subCategory and with one top layer above –

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, I've used this way finally:

```
  const { ...sportFilters } = queryData;
  const filterKeys = keys(sportFilters);
  const filterOptions = reduce(
    filterKeys,
    (acc, key) => {
       return {
         ...acc,
         [key]: map(sportFilters[key], value => ({
         value,
         label: value
       }))
     };
   },
 {}
);
```